# Some dataset fields don't appear on RDLC report

Tags: rdlc, localreport

I created dataset that contains Table View from SqlServer 2008 database.
Then I created a report (rdlc) and added the previous dataset as a source for this report.
In the code, I called a function that returns a list from My Table View type and assign this list to the created report as following:

```
ReportDataSource reportSource = new ReportDataSource();
reportSource.Name = "DataSet1";
reportSource.Value = GetData(); // returns List<MyTableViewType>
localReport.DataSources.Clear();
localReport.DataSources.Add(reportSource);
localReport.Refresh();
```

The problem is that I have three fields in the dataset don’t appear in the report although I am sure (By Debugging) that they got filled before rendering the report.

Any help will be appreciated ...
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your `MyTableViewType` class. Has the class the `Serializable` attribute set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that the dataFields name from your database is the same as declared in your report dataSource. Probably in the returned list the fields have different names.

Comment: Does not make sense since he is using a strongly typed class and does not bind the `ReportDataSource` to the database. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2011/01/03/walkthrough-working-reportviewer-with-a-complex-business-object-with-a-nested-generic-list-type-property-as-data-source-for-local-reports.aspx

Comment: Actually I solved it just like Me5 said, those three fields names in the DataSet was starting with capital letter while they were starting with small ones in the class.

Answer (score 0):

if use the contractor

```
public xx(Model dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }
```

replace with this

```
     public xx()
    {
        this.dbContext = new Model();
    }
```